# Zabbix external checks runs from bash but not from map in admin web console

Tags: zabbix

I have a python script which I have placed in /usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/ and am able to execute this from bash. I am on a RHEL 7 machine and am on Zabbix 3.x.
When I try to run the script from Monitoring > Maps > Local Network > Click on local zabbix server icon > Select my script name, I get an error stating :

- Connection timeout of 60 seconds exceeded when connecting to the zabbix server on "localhost".
- Cannot execute script

I have tried setting a different Timeout value in the zabbix_server.conf but that hasn't fixed this error.
I have attached a screenshot of this error.

Can you help me in troubleshooting this error ?

TIA

[image: Zabbix error]

Comment: Looks like this was because of a bad https proxy setting in the python code. Fixing that corrected this error. There was a https_proxy override which was set temporarily in the bash shell and that's why the code worked even with a bad proxy setting.

Answer (score 1):

Bad https proxy setting in python code. Once that was fixed this error got corrected.